# How to crawl certain amount of images from a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this code where I want to crawl images from a given website

```
from bs4 import *
import requests as rq
import os
import sys

page_url = sys.argv[1]
crawl = str(page_url)
r2 = rq.get('https://www.' + crawl + '' + '/')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, "html.parser")
images = []


image_sources = soup2.select('img')
for img in image_sources:
    images.append(img['src'])

for l in images:
    print(l)
```

how can a crawl for example only 15 images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get max 15 images you can do:

```py
...

for img in image_sources[:15]: # <--- max. 15 images
    images.append(img['src'])

...
```